# Migration do not put "unique" on my table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to modify an existing migration by doing this :

```
c:\wamp64\www\urlshortner>php artisan make:migration add_unique_to_shortened_on_urls_table_--table=urls
```

I add this code on migration file :

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::table('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unique('shortned');
    });
}
```

I ran PHP artisan migrate command but the field is not "unique" on MySQL

Can you help me please ?

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Nom du champ 'shortned' déjà utilisé (SQL: alter table `urls` add `shortned` varchar(255) not null)
```

This is the error I received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all install `doctrine/dbal` depentency. for that run `composer require doctrine/dbal`. Then modyfy the migration like

```
$table->string('shortned')->unique()->charset('')->collation('')->change();
```

then run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```php
$table->string('shortned')->unique();
```

Comment: thank you but now I received this error :    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Nom du champ 'shortned' déjà utilisé (SQL: alter table `urls` add `shortned` varchar(255) not null)

Comment: Run `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have the datas with duplicate values in your `shortned` table. so first delete all the datas from `shortned` using `Delete from shortned;`. and after that run your migration.